# how can I add a box in MATLAB figure which will show average values of the plots?

Tags: matlab-figure

I want to add a box in MATLAB figure which contains calculated average value of the plot.I know how to add legend.But, what about showing calculted value from the code?

Comment: Does "hold on" and "plot" not work? What do you mean by "a box"? Data are usually plotted as curves or lines in MATLAB figures.

Answer (score 0):

You may either use an `annotation` object, or edit the legend string.

View the `annotation` object documentation here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html

In a nutshell, you can create the annotation object, then modify its content, position, shape, etc programatically using `get()`/`set()` on its `handles` properties.

For example:

```
x = 1 : 1000;
y1 = sin ( 2 * pi * x ./ 1000 );
y2 = sin ( 2 * pi * x ./ 1000 ) + 0.25;
y1Mean = mean ( y1 );
y2Mean = mean ( y2 );

handleFigure = figure();
handlePlot = plot ( x , y1 , 'b' , x , y2 , 'r' );
handleLegend = legend ( 'y1' , 'y2' );

message1 = [ 'Mean y1 = ' , num2str ( y1Mean ) ];
handleAnnotation = annotation ( 'textbox' , [0.25 0.25 0.1 0.1] , 'string' , message1 );
```

Creates the following:
[image: Annotation Textbox]

You could then change the string in the annotation box using:

```
message2 = [ 'Mean y2 = ' , num2str ( y2Mean ) ];
set ( handleAnnotation , 'string' , message2 );
```

Which adjusts the box as follows:
[image: Annotation Textbox after changing string.]

---

To edit the legend string, simply use the following command:

```
legendString{1} = [ 'y1 (Mean ' , num2str(y1Mean) , ')' ];
legendString{2} = [ 'y2 (Mean ' , num2str(y2Mean) , ')' ];
set ( handleLegend , 'string' , legendString );
```

Which adjusts the graph to:
[image]